# c#: how to set "Created by" in dll

Tags: c#, dll

It's possible to set "Created by", when developing a new dll?

So when a user imports that dll, in the `Add Reference` Form the field "Created by" is not empty (as shown in the picture).

[image]

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to manually set the [AssemblyCompanyAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblycompanyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) in the "AssemblyInfo.cs" file, because by default it is initialized with an empty string parameter:

```
 [assembly: AssemblyCompany("My company")]
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you should write your name to the `AssemblyInfo.cs` either by directly writing to the file or by changing the values within the properties settings: Projetct Settings-->within the ribbon Application: Assembly Information-->Company

[image]